# GITHUB ACTION string chars from string

Tags: github-actions

I have set an env variable called **BRANCH** and in there I have `"release/v4.1.2"`. I'm on ubuntu and I want to update that env variable to just be left with `"v4.1.2"`. I am totally stuck. Nothing I try works.

something like this?

```
run:|
BRANCH="${BRANCH//[^0-9]/}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the Bash [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) feature, like:

```
>echo "${BRANCH#"release/"}"
v4.1.2
```

so you can combine it in your action like:

```
run:|
release="${BRANCH#"release/"}"
echo "BRANCH=${release}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

By setting an env variable, like described [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable)